# Sms retrieve API Android not working after market upload

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

The production release build was tested before upload to play store and auto-fetch OTP was working fine. But once uploaded it's not auto fetching OTP. Any reasons?

Comment: Something must have messed up. That's all I can say considering the infor you have given.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer

Comment: Are You using it to read otp ?

Comment: Something Like this Happened with me too..In my case I gave wrong AppHash to Back end Team (I gave them Debug App Hash)...but when I created release App Hash got changed.

Comment: @m3g4tr0n : Yes I am using it to read OTP. No proper Hash is shared with server team. Another strange thing is I added AppSignatureHelper class , displayed Hash for the build that was generated using signed Key. and even uploaded same build. Both Hash Keys are entrirely different. Its not like this is my first app. I have done it for couple of other apps.

Comment: How I Solved this issue: I Calculated app hash at runtime using AppSignatureHelper class and sent it with login request then the same App Hash is used to generate OTP message in the backend